# Unique Values range list

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to extract unique values from a different sheet and paste them into another. The code works pretty fast which is great. However, I cannot figure it out how to paste the data only as values and not to copy the original format as well. I know that you need to set *.PasteSpecial xlValues* to the specific range, but when I tried to do that I get the error 1004.

Any suggestions would be must appreciated. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Uniquevalues()
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim wk1 As Worksheet


Set wk = Sheets("X")
Set wk1 = Sheets("Y")


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    wk.Range("B3:B" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=wk1.Range("c4"), _  ' tried to set afer ("c4") .PasteSpecial xlValues, but it doesn't  work
    Unique:=True
    'wk1.Range("c4").PasteSpecial xlValues - tried like this as well and it doesn't work
End Sub
```

This is how I got rid of the copy format cells:

```
Sub format()

Dim wk2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long

Set wk2 = Sheets("Y")

lastrow1 = wk2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
wk2.Range("c4:c" & lastrow1).Select
With Selection
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
.Value = .Value
.ClearFormats

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: **ws** is never defined, only **wk** and **wk1**

Comment: **Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row** is not assigned to a specific worksheet.

Comment: my bad, took it from the Excel file. Corrected now

Comment: In general it is better to Copy, PasteSpecialValues, and then remove duplicates in the destination  worksheet.

Comment: I attempted an answer below.  you also weren't specifying a worksheet for the `LastRow` calculation

Comment: I think I will just use `.ClearFormats` to clear the format taken from the specific range. Just realized that I can do that. In regards to **Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row** just realized that, and you are right. Can you please guide me in how should I assigned that to **wk**? Thanks

Comment: `wk.Cells.ClearFormats`   but are there formulas in what you're copying?  It would be much easier to help you if you posted a **sample of your data** with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data I can't test this but try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Uniquevalues()

    Dim wk As Worksheet, wk1 As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
    Set wk = Sheets("X")
    Set wk1 = Sheets("Y")

    lastrow = wk.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    wk.Range("B3:B" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , wk1.Range("c4"), True

End Sub
```

See: [**Range.AdvancedFilter Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-advancedfilter-method-excel)

Comment: Just tested this now. Thanks for helping to set the "last row". It still takes the format from the previous sheet. No, there are no formulas from the data I tried to copy. There are just numbers that have conditional formatting on their cells. I will just set **.ClearFormats** as another code for the specific range and I guess it should work... Thanks again!

Comment: @alex2002 - OMG I have to ask: are you `@Alex2002` because you were *born* in 2002?  My son is Alex, born in 2004.  Is he going to be this good in 2 years?!  You're older than that, right?!  :-)

Comment: haha, yes I am older. It is the account of my little brother. But he is actually doing VBA as well. So when I am stuck, I just use his account. He started VBA by taking some online courses on **Udemy.com** - pretty cheap and great explanations. Your son should try them as well :)

Comment: So your brother was born in 2002 and uses VBA? That's awesome. (Actually that's the same age as when I started but we only had 1 computer in the school and I was the only one who knew how to work it!)   I will bookmark that site now thanks!